# Using Regex is there a way to match outside characters in a string and exclude the inside characters?

Tags: regex

I know I can exclude outside characters in a string using look-ahead and look-behind, but I'm not sure about characters in the center.

What I want is to get a match of `ABCDEF` from the string `ABC 123 DEF`.

Is this possible with a Regex string? If not, can it be accomplished another way?

**EDIT**

For more clarification, in the example above I can use the regex string `/ABC.*?DEF/` to sort of get what I want, but this includes everything matched by `.*?`. What I want is to match with something like `ABC(match whatever, but then throw it out)DEF` resulting in one single match of `ABCDEF`.

As another example, I can do the following (in sudo-code and regex):

```
string myStr = "ABC 123 DEF";
string tempMatch = RegexMatch(myStr, "(?<=ABC).*?(?=DEF)"); //Returns " 123 "
string FinalString = myStr.Replace(tempMatch, ""); //Returns "ABCDEF". This is what I want
```

Again, is there a way to do this with a single regex string?

Comment: This one example isn't really enough. Do you want `ABC...DEF` no matter what is in between? Or do you want exactly `ABC 123 DEF` but only care for the `ABCDEF`? Or do you want `ABC...123...DEF` with anything in between, but `123` *somewhere* in between? And what of this is fixed and what is variable? A list of corresponding input and output examples and a bit of clarifying explanation would help :)

Comment: @m.buettner: I suspect that he's not really worried about getting a specific regular expression that exactly solves a specific problem. I think he just wants to know whether it's possible to do it at all.

Comment: @MarkByers yes, but whether **what** is possible? Even for an abstract example, a bunch of example inputs can be found, and I think the one example given leaves room for a whole bunch of possible interpretations.

Comment: @m.buettner: He wants to know given the specific input string "ABC123DEF" is it possible to write *any* regular expression that returns a match "ABCDEF" (and not "ABC123DEF"). If you can come up with *any* regular expression that can do that for that one specific single input then I think you have answered his question.

Comment: @MarkByers but what are the parameters? Is everything fixed? Or is `123` fixed and he wants everything around that? Or is `ABC...DEF` fixed and he doesn't care what's in the middle? Or (since he refers to lookarounds), does he want to assert that there is `123` between `ABC` and `DEF` but then again only wants to retrieve `ABCDEF`? All of these are possible but require a slightly different solution.

Comment: @MikeWebb thank you. In that case, Mark Byers' answer is the way to go for you (well except that you use `.*` instead of `\d+`). But there is no other way but getting two captures and concatenating them (at least nothing that would be supported by most regex engines). You cannot cut things out from the overall match.

Comment: @MikeWebb well, you *could* (ab)use the replace syntax instead of trying to match. I'll make it an answer, to provide an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the regex replace feature in most languages does not change the string it operates on (but produces a new one), you can do it as a one-liner in most languages. Firstly, you match everything, capturing the desired parts:

```
^.*(ABC).*(DEF).*$
```

(Make sure to use the single-line/"dotall" option if your input contains line breaks!)

And then you replace this with:

```
$1$2
```

That will give you `ABCDEF` in one assignment.

Still, as outlined in the comments and in Mark's answer, the engine *does* match the stuff in between `ABC` and `DEF`. It's only the replacement convenience function that throws it out. But that is supported in pretty much every language, I would say.

**Important:** this approach will of course only work if your input string contains the desired pattern only once (assuming `ABC` and `DEF` are actually variable).

Example implementation in PHP:

```
$output = preg_replace('/^.*(ABC).*(DEF).*$/s', '$1$2', $input);
```

Or JavaScript (which does not have single-line mode):

```
var output = input.replace(/^[\s\S]*(ABC)[\s\S]*(DEF)[\s\S]*$/, '$1$2');
```

Or C#:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"^.*(ABC).*(DEF).*$", "$1$2", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks. And, yes, the desired pattern only occurs once.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression can contain multiple capturing groups. Each group must consist of consecutive characters so it's not possible to have a single group that captures what you want, but the groups themselves do not have to be contiguous so you can combine multiple groups to get your desired result.

**Regular expression**

```
(ABC).*(DEF)
```

**Captures**

```
ABC
DEF
```

See it online: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/WCJ4gC2L2I)

**Example C# code**

```
string myStr = "ABC 123 DEF";
Match m = Regex.Match(myStr, "(ABC).*(DEF)");
if (m.Success)
{
    string result = m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2].Value;  // Gives "ABCDEF"
    // ...
}
```